# Toggle connectNulls with button

Tags: highcharts

I am just starting out with Highstock and I want to provide our users with the option of toggling the connection of the null data points via a button. Here is how I have tried to solve it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bertilalexandersson/vsmn60gL/)

```
    // create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
       [...]

        plotOptions : {
            series : {
                connectNulls : false // default
            }
        },

       [...]
    });

    // Toggle connect nulls
    var connectNulls = true;
    $('#connectNulls').click(function() {
        chart.plotOptions.series.connectNulls = connectNulls;
        connectNulls = !connectNulls;
    });
```

But it has no impact on the graph. All the examples I've found so far concerning toggling on chart configuration are doing dynamic manipulation on the series via the update method, but for the connectNulls I guess this is not possible.

I can always repaint the graph from scratch but I want to avoid this if possible. Say if one user has zoomed into the graph, repainting would cause the zoom to be lost.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `series.update()` and then modify this param.

http://jsfiddle.net/vsmn60gL/3/